# Single Team Project, multiple teams default area not being set

Tags: tfs, alm

We have moved from A single collection with many team projects, to a single collection, with one team project, and just many source control folders (One for each project).

For each project we are going to use areas/teams to split things down logically.

However, we expect `The Business` who aren't TFS users will log bugs and such, via the correct team.

I have assigned default areas for the correct teams, and at some point in the move, we were able to view a team via web access, create a new Work Item, and it would use the correct Area.

For whatever reason this has now stopped - is there something I need to set to make sure it uses the correct/default area for the team?

Comment: Can you confirmed from the Work Item Areas UI that the area is still set as default area for the team?

Comment: It is - on the creation of a new bug, it's the as the Root area, not the team's default.

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar did you ever get this to work?  I have the same issue.  No matter when I do, TFS ignores the team's default area and uses the project's default area.

Comment: @SteveG Yes I did actually! See my Answer I've just posted - That worked for us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this working by making sure the Team Name had no spaces *This was the key* and area have no spaces

Before one of our teams was *Web Reports* with an area *Web Reports*, nothing worked.

Changing the Team and Area to *WebReports*, and also marked the *WebReports* area as the default team for that area, and things started working.

[image]

Comment: That seems to have done the trick!  Had a space in the area name and the team name.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the default area for each team in the Control Panel in the Web Access of your Team Foundation Server.

You should go to:

```
Control panel --> <your collection name> --> <your project name> --> <team name>
```

In the Areas tab you will see the hierarchy of the root project with all the teams beneath it. Make sure that the correct team is selected as the default area.

You can find the documentation here at MSDN: [Add and modify area and iteration paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181692.aspx)

Comment: That's how I've got it configured... when I access http://TFS/Collection/Project/Team it pulls through the root area, not the team's default - could it be a team's settings?